# "Delete" button missing on pop up menu on row bar. How to get it back?

Tags: excel, vba

I carelessly run this macro:

```
Application.CommandBars("Row").FindControl(ID:=293).Delete
```

where ID:=293 is "Delete" button when right click on row bar. Then, I find "Delete" is missing from Row Bar:

[image]

How do I get "Delete" visible again?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the row command bar using this:

```
Application.CommandBars("Row").Reset
```

Comment: Here's a good solution from Microsoft (step 1 worked for me): https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/missing-delete-function-in-excel-2016-row-column/38a98ac2-0d79-4808-8815-f5641da16c28

Comment: Just paste it into your debug window and press enter. I tried it myself (removing it and resetting it) and it worked just fine. You are doing it wrong.

Comment: Your link seems like a lot of work compared to my solution.